# Excel conditional formatting when row is not completely filled

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

[image]In Column *E* I need the Cells from E9 to E200 to be filled either green or red. Red when the respective row is completely filled from F to XJ and red if a cell is not filled from F to XJ.

BUT this condition must only be activated if at for example the Cell in Column L of that Row is filled. (so it only marks the color when the Name of the Person is filled in for example).

Is it possible to do something with conditional formatting or is VBA needed? I tried it in VBA but couldn't really get anything right..

thanks

Comment: Do you mean green when the respective row is completely filled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes use the following formulas for conditional formatting using the add new rule > use a formula to determine cells to format. Add 2 rules and set the fill colour to either red or green.

1) Green: No blanks in range using the following:

```
 =COUNTBLANK(F9:XJ9) = 0
```

2) Red:  1 or more blanks, and col L is not empty, then red using the following:

```
=AND(ISBLANK(L9) =FALSE,COUNTBLANK(F9:XJ9) >0)
```

For green (no blanks) see image:

[image: Green]

For red add another formula. See image

[image: Red]

Comment: An easier solution would just be to (non-conditionally) format the pertinent cells as red and have a single conditional formatting rule to override the red and format it as green (if the condition is satisfied). I find this to be simpler than to have two separate conditional formatting rules that are logically opposite of each other. Otherwise I agree with your answer.

Comment: Usually if I am conditional formatting something, I will non-conditionally format it as whatever is the most complicated condition, then have subsequent conditional formatting rules to handle the lesser complicated conditions for overriding the formatting.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889  I will be adding that to my tactics. Such a sensible way of doing things.